# Everytime i want to scroll in a listview by clicking on a rating bar, it was a rating performed

Tags: android, listview, scroll, ratingbar

i fought a long time with that problem without finding a solution anywhere.
I have a ListView that contains some RatingBars. Everytime i wanted to scroll and hit accidentially a ratingbar a rating was performed instead of a scroll.
Now I found a simple solution: I wrote my own RatingBar:

```
public class ScrollableRatingBar extends RatingBar {

    public ScrollableRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollableRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollableRatingBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            return true;

        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            return true;
        }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    }

}
```

What happens: if you click at a RatingBar there are 3 different MotionEvents:
-Action_DOWN: Put your finger down
-Action_MOVE: Move your finger
-Action_UP: Put your finger up

You don't want to set the rating at the action "down" or "move". So just return true to signal it has happend. If "up" comes, the programm differes itself if it is a scroll or a rating, depending what you did.

That's all!
I hope someone helps that.

EDIT:
I realize that it is a problem of Android 2.3.7 and lower.